# How to build a dictionary from a list mapping

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
extension_to_type_mapping = {
 'Metadata': ['xls', 'xml', 'xlsx'],
 'Audio': ['ac3', 'aif', 'aiff', 'flac'],
 'Video': ['avi', 'm2t', 'm2v', 'm4v', 'mov', 'mp4', 'mpg', 'mpeg', 'mxf'],
 'Subtitles/Captions': ['cap', 'cc', 'itt', 'scc', 'srt'],
 'Image': ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'psd', 'tif', 'tiff', 'ts', 'vob', 'wav'],
 'Other': [None,]
}
```

I would like to be able to reverse the mapping so I can call:

```
MAPPING['jpg'] ==> 'Metadata'
```

So far I have:

```
MAPPING = {}
for key, list in extension_to_type_mapping.items():
    for i in list:
        MAPPING[i] = key
```

Is there a list comprehension or something simpler (itertools?) to do this?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want a function that accepts a value and a dictionary, and then tells you for which key in the dictionary that value appears in the collection that is that key's value? Also, the specific example you give doesn't seem to follow from the example dictionary. Shouldn't it be `'Image'` instead of `'Metadata'`? It also seems like there could be sentinel values in the value collections, like `None`, that could appear for more than one key. If that ever happens, the mapping isn't 1-to-1 so you'll probably just have the final key for which that sentinel value appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> extension_to_type_mapping = {
...     'Metadata': ['xls', 'xml', 'xlsx'],
...     'Audio': ['ac3', 'aif', 'aiff', 'flac'],
...     'Video': ['avi', 'm2t', 'm2v', 'm4v', 'mov', 'mp4', 'mpg', 'mpeg', 'mxf'],
...     'Subtitles/Captions': ['cap', 'cc', 'itt', 'scc', 'srt'],
...     'Image': ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'psd', 'tif', 'tiff', 'ts', 'vob', 'wav'],
...     'Other': [None,]
... }
>>> MAPPING = {ext: type_ for type_, exts in extension_to_type_mapping.items()
               for ext in exts}
>>> MAPPING['jpg']
'Image'
```

---

BTW, instead of your own mappings, you can also use [`mimetypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html):

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('something.jpg')
('image/jpeg', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> {v:k for k, vs in extension_to_type_mapping.items() for v in vs}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension (from Python 2.7 onwards) -

```
MAPPING = {i:key for key,item in extension_to_type_mapping.items() for i in item}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MAPPING = dict()
for k, v in extension_to_type_mapping.items():
    MAPPING.update((i,k) for i in v)
```